# Gradle: how to get all the module dependencies of a project

Tags: android, gradle, checkstyle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to write a Gradle Plugin that runs Checkstyle over all the source code of a specific Android app, including all the variants and all the library modules that the app is using and generate a single report without duplicate errors. Currently I am able to run it through all the variants successfully and generate a report without duplications, but I have no idea **how to get the list of modules** that the app is using.

So, basically, if I have a project with this structure:

```
MyProject
+-MyAppFoo
+-MyAppBar
+-FeatureA
+-FeatureB
+-FeatureC
+-Core
```

And the app `MyAppFoo` has dependencies on the modules `FeatureA` and `FeatureC` and `FeatureA` depends on `Core` I would like to be able to access the project instance of `FeatureA`, `Core` and `FeatureC` to get their sources and classpaths.

My current code looks like this and I am applying it directly to only one app module of the project (eg. `MyAppFoo`):

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

afterEvaluate {
    def variants
    if (project.plugins.hasPlugin('com.android.application')) {
        variants = android.applicationVariants
    } else if (project.plugins.hasPlugin('com.android.library')) {
        variants = android.libraryVariants
    } else {
        return
    }

    def dependsOn = []
    def classpath
    def source
    variants.all { variant ->

        dependsOn << variant.javaCompiler
        if (!source) {
            source = variant.javaCompiler.source.filter { p ->
                return p.getPath().contains("${project.projectDir}/src/main/")
            }
        }
        source += variant.javaCompiler.source.filter { p ->
            return !p.getPath().contains("${project.projectDir}/src/main/")
        }
        if (!classpath) {
            classpath = project.fileTree(variant.javaCompiler.destinationDir)
        } else {
            classpath += project.fileTree(variant.javaCompiler.destinationDir)
        }
    }

    def checkstyle = project.tasks.create "checkstyle", Checkstyle
    checkstyle.group = "Verification"
    checkstyle.dependsOn dependsOn
    checkstyle.source source
    checkstyle.classpath = classpath
    checkstyle.exclude('**/BuildConfig.java')
    checkstyle.exclude('**/R.java')
    checkstyle.exclude('**/BR.java')
    checkstyle.showViolations true
    project.tasks.getByName("check").dependsOn checkstyle
}
```

What I would like to have is a list of `project`s containing only the modules that my `MyAppFoo` is using, this whay when I run `gradle :MyAppFoo:checkstyle` I want to run it on the modules `MyAppFoo`, `FeatureA`, `Core` and `FeatureC`.